# How to compute non-repeatable vertices for a Cube

Tags: vectors

Given 8 edge vertices, how can I compute the vectors of the points in-between all of them using maths ?

For example, I have a density, which is how many points should be added between all sections, so if that is 2 and my edges are at (1, 0, 1) and (-1, 0 ,1), they are going to be somewhere around (0.33, 0, 1) and (-0.33, 0, 1).

How can I compute all these coordinates given a density N and the initial 8 vertices.

Comment: Using the line going through two points you can get to any point between them, if that's what you want.

Comment: $P=(1,0,1) (1-t)+(-1,0,1) t$ gives you all the points between $(1,0,1)$ and $(-1,0,1)$ when $t$ varies between $0$ and $1$. In your example, set $t=1/3$ and $t=2/3$.